# In Backgammon, when can the dice be doubled?

Tags: backgammon

I basically understand the principle of doubling: using the doubling cube to double the stakes of the current game. I'm not sure when the dice rolled can be double for 4 moves. Is that only when the doubling cube is used? Or can it be done any time within a game? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing two uses of the word *double*.  If you roll doubles (e.g both dice show 3) you move not two but four counters three spaces ('Movement, 3' [here](http://usbgf.org/learn-backgammon/rules-of-backgammon/)).

You can also use the doubling die to increase the stakes at certain times; this has no effect on the game unless your opponent chooses to resign the game rather than play for (and lose) the higher stakes( '[Doubling'](http://usbgf.org/learn-backgammon/rules-of-backgammon/)).

Comment: @Bob: To close this off, you could accept this answer, (click the tick to the left). Or, of course, you could ask for any further clarification.